# Driver for a large amount of discrete LEDs

Tags: led, led-driver

I am building one of those [LED "supercomputer" panels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7f8jgvvJe-Q) around this [power supply.](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/MEAN-WELL/NPF-40D-12?qs=7PCaVhlmG1o8HBnJn6yCXQ%3D%3D) The LEDs I am using are 3 V 40 mA. My plan is to use 336 LEDs in four arrays of 84 parallel LEDs and wire the four arrays in series. Can someone check my math and tell me if that would work or if I am completely mad?

Edit: The LEDs I'm using are RGB color changing, they are effectively on all the time. I added a rough schematic and a scaled-down version running standard LEDs (ignore the differences in brightness). The circled groups are in parallel. The four groups are in series running from 9 V with a 10 Ω series resistor. This is what I want to do but on a larger scale.
[image: Schematic][image: Mockup]

Comment: No, you can't wire the arrays in series. Things in series must have the same value of current flowing through them at all times, and that certainly isn't true of these arrays of self-flashing LEDs. You'll need to have all 336 LEDs in parallel across a low-voltage, high-current power supply.

Comment: That’s a constant current supply, so will try to pump a steady current through the LEDs regardless of how many are switched on at any time, except that it won’t output more than 12V if the desired current can’t be achieved.  With arrays of 84 LEDs they will average out well most of the time, but on the first occasion where there’s just one LED on in the array, it will try to pump all the current through it, which is unlikely to end well.  As they’re self-flashing I’d guess that they will also regulate current to some degree, so as Dave Tweed suggests you probably need a 3V constant voltage

Comment: …supply with all LEDs in parallel.

Comment: Without specification of the "LED"s, don't expect more than guesswork, if well informed.